# Drop Postgresql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, npgsql, drop-database

I am trying to drop a database from aspnet(c#). But It is giving me an error: There are some connections.
If I delete all the connections:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend (pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE pg_stat_activity.pid <> pg_backend_pid() and pg_stat_activity.datname = 'databsename';
```

It gives me another error: connection is lose.

It is like if i execute the sentence above, It is closing all my connections.

I use npgsql as connector.

Here my code:
The code inside a button:

```
NpgsqlConnection _connPgComienzo = new NpgsqlConnection("my_connection_to_other_DDBB_in_the_same_server;");

    try
    {

        _connPgComienzo.Open();
        FileInfo file1 = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("desconectar.sql"));
        string script_crear_bbdd = file1.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
        var m_createdb_cmd1 = new NpgsqlCommand(script_crear_bbdd, _connPgComienzo);
        m_createdb_cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _connPgComienzo.Close();

        _connPgComienzo.Open();
        FileInfo file2 = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("drop_bbdd.sql"));
        string script_crear_bbdd2 = file2.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
        var m_createdb_cmd2 = new NpgsqlCommand(script_crear_bbdd2, _connPgComienzo);
        m_createdb_cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _connPgComienzo.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

desconectar.slq:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend (pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE pid <> pg_backend_pid() AND pg_stat_activity.datname = 'theDDBBIWantToDrop';
```

drop_bbdd.sql:

```
 DROP DATABASE theDDBBIWantToDrop;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449420/postgresql-unable-to-drop-database-because-of-some-auto-connections-to-db?rq=1

Comment: It is not working for me. 
And I dont want to prevent connecting, I want to drop the database suddenly.
I edit to say that yes, It is working in a postgresql client(maestro), but not working in C#

Comment: Show us the code that is not working. Edit your question and paste it.

Comment: @Za7pi can you terminate your database using the above query using `pAdmin` or whatever you use ??

Comment: @Za7pi are you trying to `restore` `PostgreSQL-Database` using `c#` or what ??

Comment: No, I am trying to drop a database using c#

Comment: does `db` in your connection string and `db` you want to drop is same ??

Comment: No, it is not the same

Comment: @Za7pi just have a look on my ans

Comment: Your `catch (Exception ex) {}` is muting all errors. Please add some diagnostics to it, e.g. `Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())` then see what's the error messsage. It will help pinpointing the cause. EDIT: I've just realized that your app is a web app. So add some logging to see what's the exact error message.

Comment: Yes, It is a web app. I am catching the errors but I dont put It here. The error is: error: database "myDDBB" is being accessed by other users

Answer (score 0):

*Try to use `psql` to terminate your `postgreSQL database`

- for that you have to create a `batch file(*.bat)` using c#,
  This .bat file must contain the following script to terminate your
  database connection

> psql -U postgres  -d postgres -c SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname ='yourdb'

*For example*

```
Private Sub TerminateDBactivity()
    Dim strPG_dumpPath As String
    Dim strSub As String
    strPG_dumpPath = Application.StartupPath.ToString()
    strPG_dumpPath = strPG_dumpPath.Replace("\", "\\")
    Dim a As Integer = strPG_dumpPath.IndexOf(":\\", 0)
    a = a + 2
    strSub = strPG_dumpPath.Substring(0, (a - 2))
    strPG_dumpPath = strPG_dumpPath.Substring(a, (strPG_dumpPath.Length - a))
    Dim sbSB1 As New StringBuilder(strPG_dumpPath)
    sbSB1 = sbSB1.Replace("\\", vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "cd ")
    Dim sbSB2 As New StringBuilder("cd /D ")
    sbSB2 = sbSB2.Append(strSub)
    sbSB2 = sbSB2.Append(":\")
    sbSB1 = sbSB2.Append(sbSB1)
    sbSB1 = sbSB1.Append(vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "cd PG" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
    Dim sw As New StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath.ToString() & "\PG\pgTerminate.bat")
    If sbSB1.Length <> 0 Then
        sbSB1 = sbSB1.Append("psql -U postgres  -d postgres -c ""SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = '" & gStrDBName & "';")
        sw.WriteLine(sbSB1)
        sw.Dispose()
        sw.Close()
        Dim processDB As New ProcessStartInfo
        processDB.FileName = Application.StartupPath.ToString() & "\PG\pgTerminate.bat"
        processDB.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        Process.Start(processDB).WaitForExit()
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
    End If
End Sub
```

- this code will create `pgTerminate.bat` file in this path `D:\Apps\RSTAR PGSQL DOTCONNECT\bin\Debug\PG`
- `pgTerminate.bat` looks like

  cd /D D:\Apps

> ```
> cd RSTAR PGSQL DOTCONNECT
>
> cd bin
>
> cd Debug
>
> cd PG
>
> psql -U postgres  -d postgres -c SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'mydb';
> ```

Note : before trying code you should manually create terminate bat file and test whether its working or not

Comment: The bat is ok? 
 Is this line inside bat or outside?
`cd /D D:\Apps`

Comment: @Za7pi its inside only...that defines the path to `psql` in your case this will change

Comment: My code:
 `string str_Path = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\run.bat";
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(str_Path);
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process batchProcess = new Process();
            batchProcess.StartInfo = processInfo;
            batchProcess.Start();`
bat:
`cd RSTAR PGSQL DOTCONNECT
cd bin
cd Debug
cd PG
psql -U postgres  -d postgres -c SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'DDBB';`
error: database "myDDBB" is being accessed by other users