# How to drop database which has some sessions open

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to drop a database using the following command and I get an error

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb;
There are 5 other sessions using the database.
```

Is there any sql statement/sequence of queries which which drops database killing all the open sessions? I can only use commnand line.

I tried `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE  pid <> pg_backend_pid() AND datname = 'mydb';` and also tried restarting postgres service which ideally should have worked but it did not.

Comment: Had you tried [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17449420/6656706).

Answer (score 1):

OK the followoing command worked for me great

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'mydb' AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```