# schematool failing metastore validation for Hive 1.1.0

Tags: hive, cloudera

I just deployed Cloudera 5.12 and I'm installing Hive. Following the instructions, I run

```
\i /usr/lib/hive/scripts/metastore/upgrade/postgres/hive-schema-1.1.0.postgres.sql
```

as a final step, to create the metastore. When I run the schematool validation

```
schematool -dbType postgres -validate
```

I get an error:

```
Validating metastore schema tables
Table(s) [ [compaction_queue, completed_txn_components, hive_locks, next_compaction_queue_id, next_lock_id, next_txn_id, txn_components, txns] ] are missing from the metastore database schema.
Failed in schema table validation.
[FAIL]
```

Everything else is SUCCESS and I can access the Hive databases without problems. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Are you referring to this instructions? https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_hive_schema_tool.html

Comment: Yes, those ones.

Comment: Are you using Cloudera Manager?

Comment: No, I'm doing the installation on the command line.

Comment: Did you run scm_prepare_database.sh? If yes, can you share `schematool -info` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work recreating the Hive metastore using `schematool`. I had to first drop the current metastore on postgreSQL, using the information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449420/postgresql-unable-to-drop-database-because-of-some-auto-connections-to-db):

```
> su - postgres
> psql

REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE thedb FROM public;
SELECT pid, pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE datname = current_database() AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
drop metastore;
```

and then recreating using

```
/usr/lib/hive/bin/schematool -dbType postgres -initSchema -verbose -userName hiveuser -passWord thepassword
```

Validation worked afterwards:

```
> /usr/lib/hive/bin/schematool -dbType postgres -validate
Starting metastore validation

Validating schema version
Succeeded in schema version validation.
[SUCCESS]

Validating sequence number for SEQUENCE_TABLE
Succeeded in sequence number validation for SEQUENCE_TABLE.
[SUCCESS]

Validating metastore schema tables
Succeeded in schema table validation.
[SUCCESS]

Validating DFS locations
Succeeded in DFS location validation.
[SUCCESS]

Validating columns for incorrect NULL values.
Succeeded in column validation for incorrect NULL values.
[SUCCESS]

Done with metastore validation: [SUCCESS]
schemaTool completed
```

So I think that if there's a bug, it's on the metastore creation step:

```
\i /usr/lib/hive/scripts/metastore/upgrade/postgres/hive-schema-1.1.0.postgres.sql
```

detailed on the [Cloudera installation manual](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_hive_metastore_configure.html#topic_18_4_3__title_524).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug. Here is what I found:

```
$ find . -name "*.sql" -print |xargs grep compaction_queue
./postgres/hive-txn-schema-0.14.0.postgres.sql:CREATE TABLE "compaction_queue" (
./postgres/hive-txn-schema-0.14.0.postgres.sql:CREATE TABLE "next_compaction_queue_id" (
./postgres/hive-txn-schema-0.14.0.postgres.sql:INSERT INTO "next_compaction_queue_id" VALUES(1);
./postgres/hive-schema-0.14.0.postgres.sql:CREATE TABLE "compaction_queue" (
./postgres/hive-schema-0.14.0.postgres.sql:CREATE TABLE "next_compaction_queue_id" (
./postgres/hive-schema-0.14.0.postgres.sql:INSERT INTO "next_compaction_queue_id" VALUES(1);
```

As you can see, the table `next_compaction_queue_id` only exists in schema version 0.14 for postgresql. It does not exist in any of other versions or any other database type. I do not believe these are used. If you have Cloudera Support, please create a support case and ask support to create a jira.

A workaround would be to find the table create statements of the **CLAIMED** missing tables in the `hive-schema-0.14.0.postgres.sql` file and add these tables to your Hive metastore database. Since they are not used, it won't harm anything, but it will get rid of the error in your schematool command.