# How to stop postgresql PGPOOL replication

Tags: database, postgresql, database-replication, bitnami, pgpool

I'm trying postgres database backup and restore. The access to postgres is through pgpool.

To achieve the back up I am following the official postgres pg_dumpall documentation.

Commands taken from postgres website: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-pg-dumpall.html

```
$ pg_dumpall > db.out
To reload database(s) from this file, you can use:
$ psql -f db.out postgres
```

The backup works fine.

However, when attempting to restore, I'm getting the following error because of replication feature enabled by pgpool.

```
psql:tmp/backup/postgresDump/pg_data.out:15: ERROR:  database "xyz" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
```

Here are the following ideas I tried by browsing other SO questions.

1. I tried to update active='f' in pg_catalog.pg_replication_slots view. It failed with the error below

```
DETAIL:  Views that do not select from a single table or view are not automatically updatable.
HINT:  To enable updating the view, provide an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger or an unconditional ON UPDATE DO INSTEAD rule.
```

2. List the process ids for the replication slot and used pg_terminate_backend along with the pid, followed by restore.
   Command to terminate the replication slot

```
psql -U postgres -h pgpool.default.cluster.local -c "SELECT pg_terminate_backend(3402)"
 pg_terminate_backend 
----------------------
 f
(1 row)
```

As per the second answer in this link, [Postgresql - unable to drop database because of some auto connections to DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449420/postgresql-unable-to-drop-database-because-of-some-auto-connections-to-db)
I executed the terminate_backend command multiple times until it returned 0 results. Although this step was successful, restore failed with error saying

```
psql:tmp/postgresDump/pg_data.out:14: ERROR:  database "xyz" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
```

Looks like as soon as I drop a replication slot, the pgpool recreates the replication slot and establishes a connection for it.

3. Tried by dropping the replication_slot following the official documentation.
   https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-admin.html

```
psql -U postgres -h pgpool.default.local -c "select pg_drop_replication_slot('repmgr_slot_1001');"
ERROR:  replication slot "repmgr_slot_1001" is active for PID 3402
```

Any information on how to execute restore functionality through psql   is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to restore into a system that is already populated?

Comment: 'db.out' and 'pg_data.out' are different files.

Comment: I would like to perform backup periodically and restore them if need be to troubleshoot issues. pg_data.out and db.out are two different file names. In my example, I used pg_data.out as a filename.