# Redshift Serverless Terminate Active Connections?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

I have a Redshift Serverless database that I need to delete. When I run the command:

```
drop database [my_database_name]
```

an error is returned:

> SQL Error [55006]: ERROR: database "[my_database_name]" is being accessed by
> other users

The error makes sense. I need to close the active connections before dropping the database. But how on earth do we do this in Redshift Serverless?

In a traditional Redshift Cluster (Non-Serverless), you can query active sessions with:

```
select *
from pg_catalog.stv_sessions
```

and drop individual connections with:

```
SELECT PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND([PID])
```

But trying to query `pg_catalog.stv_sessions` on Redshift Serverless returns:

> SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for relation stv_sessions

The user I'm connected with is a super user so should have all allowed functionality. So, how do we see a list of active connections on Redshift Serverless?

Answer (score 1):

Found reference to the `pg_stat_activity` table in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24795713/7252531).

Querying that object returned multiple connections. Killed them using the `procpid` and dropped the database.